# Odie's EXCELTABLE.GETROWS() returns ORA-20731: Error at position 632243, expecting a [String] record

Tags: oracle, plsql, apex

I have a requirement where I have to read the compressed zip blob of XLS files in the Oracle database 19c, and process the sheets inside each XLS file, using PLSQL.

I am using APEX_ZIP package and Odie's EXCELTABLE for this.

I am able to do it by first getting the individual Excel file BLOBs using apex_zip package
and passing the BLOB to `EXCELTable.GetRows`to read the Excel sheets in the BLOB.

It works fine for few Excel sheets but for a few it gives me this error:

> ORA-20731: Error at position 632243, expecting a [String] record

The sheets are all Character data.

This is a snippet of the code I use:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM Table( 
ExcelTable.getRows(
(select fileblob from md_blob where lower(filename) like '%renew%')
,ExcelTableSheetList('Ownership - RENEW')
,' "COL1" varchar2(200 char) 
   , "COL2" varchar2(200 char)
   , "COL3" varchar2(200 char)
   , "COL4" varchar2(200 char)
   , "COL5" varchar2(200 char)
   , "COL6" varchar2(200 char)
   , "COL7" varchar2(200 char)
   , "COL8" varchar2(200 char)'
, '9:10'
)
)
;
```

Any thoughts on how to deal with it?
There is data in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to get the files as **XLSX**, not **XLS**, you can use the [APEX_DATA_PARSER](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.1/aeapi/PARSE-Function.html#GUID-B815CF74-C469-4F78-9433-643D1339E930) package to query the Excel file as if it was a table. This makes it much easier as you will not need to write any code of your own to unzip the files and dig through the contents.